# Getting Docker to recognize nvidia graphics card on mac

Tags: docker, nvidia, boot2docker

When I am in my container, I run

```
 lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

and nothing shows.

When I run ./deviceQuery from the samples NVIDIA provides I get

```
 no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

I know I have a nvidia driver on my mac. I just can't figure out how to get my docker container to realize that.

Answer (score 4):

On OS X, docker is a container running inside a separate virtualbox vm which does not expose the host GPU.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to make the graphics card available in the Virtual Box VM. I'm not sure how to do that, but this looks like it might help:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-video

Once you've got it mounted within the VM, then you can also share it with the container.

Comment: That's experimental support that doesn't include OS X. There is some kind of CUDA passthrough for virtualbox on linux, supposedly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but [this guy](http://kartoza.com/how-to-run-a-linux-gui-application-on-osx-using-docker/) says that he can run native X11 Apps on a Mac using a beta docker client called [Kinematic](https://kitematic.com/) along with [socat](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2013/10/10/how-to-run-socat-on-mac-os-x/), [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/), and [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html), and he seems to imply that NVidia driver issues were thus avoided. This looks worth a try!

Comment: That's not going to help, it's a setup in which the docker vm runs an X11 app by talking to an X11 server on the host.

Comment: @pvg, I agree that my suggested links are all about running an X11 application in a Docker container, which is not (at all) the same thing as being able to see the nvidia card. But that's the nature of workarounds in general. Given what we know from the Original Question, how can we be sure that user678392 is _not_ ultimately interested in running an X11 application? If this really turns out to be irrelevant then I will gladly remove my answer.

Comment: question is a little vague, granted, but we do know user is asking about nVidia and is running the deviceQuery utility which comes with the CUDA Samples. CUDA itself is an nVidia-specific thing. So it seems very likely user is trying to do some sort of CUDA thing rather than just attempting to get a video driver or gui working. And that possibly they didn't realize that on OS X a docker container is really a linux VM.